# algorithm to encode and decode 176 bit to 80 bit

Tags: algorithm, bit

I want a simple algorithm to compress 176 bit to 80 bit by encoding and decode it again from 80 bit to 176 bit ?

Comment: Please give more detailed information about your problem and the goal you're trying to achieve. Compression? Audio encoding?

Comment: Are you really asking for a way to compress 176 bits of data to 80 bits?  Or is there more to this question?

Comment: is the goal is the problem I just need to compress it and decompress it

Comment: yes I need only way to encode and decode

Comment: It greatly depends on the randomness of the 176 bits. See entropy keyword. Compression only works if the source is predictable in some way, one way being that it contains redundancy.

Comment: @salamonti could you possibly give us some insight on the 176 bits data content to help us help you?

Answer (score 4):

Because of the [pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), it can't be done.
There are 9.5*10^52 different values that can be expressed in 176 bits,  but there are only 1.2*10^24 different values that can be expressed in 80 bits.  You can't map every 176 bit value to an 80-bit value.

If this were possible, you could fit an infinite amount of data in 80 bits by repeated compression.

That being said, if there's something you know about the 176-bit values, then there might be ways to do it.  Say you know that the larger values would only ever 22 literal digits: e.g. strings like "11223344556677889900" or "1111111111111111111111".  In this case, the possible set of inputs would be seriously reduced - and you'd be able to map each of those values to an 80 bit value.

Comment: +1 for the pigeonhole principle :-)

Comment: -1 because it's misleading. 176 zeros in a row can be compressed down to 9 bits quite simply with runlength encoding. ( first bit to 0, then 8 bits coding 176 repetitions). I do agree that *total random* codes do require 176 bits though.

Comment: I removed the downvote because of the edit.

Comment: @Laurent: I expanded my answer a bit.  Given the question, there is no way to universally compress 176 bits to 80, but there may be ways to "cheat" if lossy compression is good enough, or take advantage of special knowledge of the input data.

Answer (score 2):

That isn't possible.

A 176 bit number has as 2^176 different combinations. It isn't possible to express each one of these combinations as a different 80 bit number, which only has 2^80 combinations. That's just like asking to compress a 4 digit number into a 3 digit number and back again.

Depending on what kind of data you're working with, this is possible with losses. Care to explain what you're doing?

Comment: So zipping a file involves magic?

Comment: I'm saying it's not possible to represent all 176 bit numbers as unique 80 bit numbers. Not all files can be zipped, some files would be zipped to bigger than the original.

Comment: @Laurent: Zipping a file isn't always going to make a file smaller.  Given non-random data, there's nearly always enough redundancy that it can reduce the file size somewhat, but the amount it can compress is very dependent on the amount of entropy in the input file.

Comment: @Laurent' Nope, but it exploits redundancy or patterns in the input data. 176 bits could be compressed into 80 bits if not all 176 bit patterns are possible. If, say, you know that there will never be a run of 1's or 0's shorter than some number n, a run-length encoding could be feasible. But unless there are some constraints for the input pattern and its possible values are a subset of the 2^176 possibilities, you won't be able to cram it into 80 bits.

Comment: I totally agree. I only wanted to stress that it might and might not be possible based on source effective entropy. We do miss some information from OP before definitive answers :)

Comment: Slightly off topic, but isn't it noticeable how excited programmers get when they can confront a theoretical problem again? I think maybe we're all nostalgic for our student years :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is a description of a rather simple algorithm if you want to implement it yourself:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ77_and_LZ78

If you google more, there was a page with a very detailed explanation how it works in practice, I just can't find it right now.

Or, just use a compression library, for example `zlib` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zlib).